# How to mark the matches separately as expected?

Tags: javascript, regex

I know what is happening, but I do not know how to solve it because I am a novice in regular expressions.

The regular expression, takes all the expression, because it takes the initial brackets of `{{username` and the end of `day}}`, then it wraps all the code between them.

How should the regular expression be?

```js
var str = "Welcome back {{username}}, how are you ? today is {{day}}",
    regex = /{{.+}}/g,
    matches = str.match(regex);
    
 console.log(matches); // I was waiting for : [{{username}}, {{day}}]
```

Comment: `/{{.+}}/g` => `/{{.+?}}/g` / `/{{.*?}}/g` / `/{{\w+}}/g`

Comment: Use `{{[^}]+}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the non-greedy modifier `?` after your `+` quantifier:

```js
var str = "Welcome back {{username}}, how are you ? today is {{day}}",
    regex = /{{.+?}}/g,
    matches = str.match(regex);
    
 console.log(matches); // I was waiting for : [{{username}}, {{day}}]
```